# Random walk on the 2-d plane, integer positive steps

Tags: probability, algebra-precalculus

We start from the point $(0,0)$ of the 2-d plane. With every step, we increase by $1$ only one of the two coordinates: $x$ with probability $p$ or $y$ with probability $q=1-p$. After $n$ steps, we are presented with a list of $n$ 2-dimensional points, not counting $(0,0)$. Show that the probability of this list having **at least** one point of the form $(x_0,y_0)$ where $y_0>x_0$ is always less than or equal to $q/p$.

(The original question works with a random integer walk, with the probabilities stated before, on the x-y plane and a straight line $y=x+\frac{1}{2}$. Show that the probability of having crossed the line at least once after $n$ steps is always $\le q/p$. I'll talk with this terminology since it's what I worked with until now)

I've worked really hard on this problem and still can't find a way to prove the inequality.
I've even found an almost explicit answer to the probability, here is my reasoning:

The probability of crossing the line from the coordinate $(a,a)$ to the point $(a,a+1)$ is $q$ times the probability of arriving to $(a,a)$ without ever crossing the line. This last probability I found being equal to $$(pq)^a\cdot2^{[a(a-1)/2]}$$(I'm not showing the reasoning behind but I'll do it if you ask me so). So the probability of crossing the line for the first time at the coordinate $(a,a)$ is $q(pq)^a\cdot2^{[a(a-1)/2]}$. Obviously, $a=\frac{n}{2}$ but it's not relevant for our proof. If we sum up the cases from $a=0$ all the way up to infinity we should get the final probability and this should be less than or equal to $q/p$. So we can solve the problem just by proving $$q\sum_{a=0}^{\infty}\left[(pq)^a\cdot2^{[a(a-1)/2]}\right]\le\frac{q}{p}$$Is my reasoning correct? Can I prove this inequality?

Note that there are most likely simpler and more straightforward methods, like a sort of induction or some other clever stuff, but I just can't think of any efficient one. Any solution or hint, even if very light, or very different from mine is hugely appreciated. Thanks for your time :)

Comment: This looks not the same as [Bertrand's ballot theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_ballot_theorem) but related

Comment: @Henry it sure does! I'll check it out as soon as I can, thanks for the suggestion

Comment: The difference $d_i = (x_i - y_i)$ changes with each turn. With probability $p$ it increases by $1$. With probability $q$, it decreases by $1$. The probability you are after is $1$ minus the probability $d_i \ge 0$ for all $i$.